# how to save two sets of ids as a set in an object like structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have a json response which looks like below. I want to save only the attachmentId and txnId from this as an object. How do I loop through this amd save in object? How do i do this in javascript?

````
  {
    date: '2022-07-18T17:08:00Z',
    attachmentId: 'a0722115-6f02-4995-9814-9cf48ff424e1',
    txnId: '9e6c83c6-3f6f-4023-855e-1c933f7af0bf',
    status: 'completed'
  },
  {
    date: '2022-07-18T16:53:10Z',
    attachmentId: 'e5795e12-2cb1-4051-a018-704cf19e0d0d',
    txnId: '06b37132-0aa0-49fa-b442-8afda800006d',
    status: 'completed'
  },
  {
    date: '2022-07-13T21:55:40Z',
    attachmentId: '0490414b-0c78-4335-8c7c-fa6f6f3a227e',
    txnId: '42a6e317-4e16-4cb4-a267-74c0c1c7d3b5',
    status: 'completed'
  }
]```
````

Comment: What do you mean "send as a pair".  There is no "pair" type in Javascript.  You can do `{attachmentId: 'a0722115-6f02-4995-9814-9cf48ff424e1', txnId: '9e6c83c6-3f6f-4023-855e-1c933f7af0bf'}` and pass just that object.  Or, you can put the two IDs in an array with an implied ordering for which is which and pass this: `['a0722115-6f02-4995-9814-9cf48ff424e1', '9e6c83c6-3f6f-4023-855e-1c933f7af0bf']` or you could combine them into one string with a separator like this: `'a0722115-6f02-4995-9814-9cf48ff424e1:9e6c83c6-3f6f-4023-855e-1c933f7af0bf'` or invent some other scheme.

Comment: Sorry I’m new to JavaScript. I want to save it as an object. How do I loop through this n save it in the object?

Comment: It's unclear what you want the output to be.  You start with an array of objects where each object has a number of properties.  What do you want the output  to be?  You can loop through this array of objects and just pass each object to some function that can then just use the two ids as it sees fit.  You don't have to remove the other properties.  Your function can just ignore the other properties.  Still not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to `map` the array to the new values, in this case, an object with just the attachment id and txnID.

```js
const data = [{
    date: '2022-07-18T17:08:00Z',
    attachmentId: 'a0722115-6f02-4995-9814-9cf48ff424e1',
    txnId: '9e6c83c6-3f6f-4023-855e-1c933f7af0bf',
    status: 'completed'
  },
  {
    date: '2022-07-18T16:53:10Z',
    attachmentId: 'e5795e12-2cb1-4051-a018-704cf19e0d0d',
    txnId: '06b37132-0aa0-49fa-b442-8afda800006d',
    status: 'completed'
  },
  {
    date: '2022-07-13T21:55:40Z',
    attachmentId: '0490414b-0c78-4335-8c7c-fa6f6f3a227e',
    txnId: '42a6e317-4e16-4cb4-a267-74c0c1c7d3b5',
    status: 'completed'
  }
]

const asObject = data.map(obj => ({attachmentId:obj.attachmentId, txnId:obj.txnId}))
console.log(asObject)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I suspect the OP doesn't actually need to do this.  They can just pass the original array to whatever function wants to use it and that function can just pay attention to only the two id values that it is interested in.

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = [{
  date: '2022-07-18T17:08:00Z',
  attachmentId: 'a0722115-6f02-4995-9814-9cf48ff424e1',
  txnId: '9e6c83c6-3f6f-4023-855e-1c933f7af0bf',
  status: 'completed'
}, {
  date: '2022-07-18T16:53:10Z',
  attachmentId: 'e5795e12-2cb1-4051-a018-704cf19e0d0d',
  txnId: '06b37132-0aa0-49fa-b442-8afda800006d',
  status: 'completed'
}, {
  date: '2022-07-13T21:55:40Z',
  attachmentId: '0490414b-0c78-4335-8c7c-fa6f6f3a227e',
  txnId: '42a6e317-4e16-4cb4-a267-74c0c1c7d3b5',
  status: 'completed'
}]

let b  = []
a.forEach((obj,id)  => { b[id] = ({attachmentId,txnId} = obj, {attachmentId,txnId}) })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.